# How to tell what type of Java error you're getting in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

So As previously stated in another post, I'm currently in school for a Java class.  I am using eclipse, but I am trying to learn the difference between the errors I get in the console.  I don't believe it is telling me what error I am getting.  So, what is the best way to tell the difference?

Here is my code that I know is failing and I know why it is failing, "theres no data in the Array"  I just don't know what type of error I am getting.

```
int[][] a = {{5,2,8,4},{}};
System.out.println(a[1][2]);
```

error that I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" 123
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at test.main(test.java:82)
```

I apologize for not being clear before.  I need to understand the difference between a Compile error, Run-time error, Logical Error and Syntax error.  And which category would this fall under?

Comment: Your question is unclear, doesn't `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` tell you what type of error you're getting?

Comment: 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' is the error type.

Comment: I guess my question is unclear.  Sorry,  Basically,  How do I know what if its a logical error, Compile error, run time error or syntax error.

Comment: @RichTalcik :Logic error means that the logic behind the program is bad.  Compile error means that the error occurred when compiling the program (before it ran).  Runtime error means that the error occurred while the program was running, and Syntax error is like a "spelling" error for programming.  As for the type of your error, **I recommend you figure it out**.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, array index starts from 0. The 2D array does not have a row at `a[1]`. So, you are going out of bounds since the length of the array at `a[1]` is 0. At runtime, when you try to access `a[1][2]`, it is out of bounds and thus the JVM throws the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

You could try adding elements to the initial array to:

```
int[][] a = {{5,2,8,4},{1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. The array `a[1]` is empty, and so when you try to read from position `2` Java is going to complain because the referenced memory location is outside the bounds of the array `a[1]`.

This is a language safety feature of Java that is supposed to keep you from doing dangerous things. In a language like C where there is no default `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`, accessing memory locations outside of the bounds of an array can sometimes result in segmentation violations that crash your program, and even if that doesn't happen, it will often return random data and should be considered a bug.